# knex.js query-response event ins not triggered when working with streams

Tags: knex.js

We use the query-response event to log the sql query with response time, everyting worked well until we switched working with streams.

```
knexClient.on('query-response', () => {   
  console.log('query-response triggered!'); 
});
const records = [];
const readableStream = knexClient.raw('select * from columns').stream();
for await (const record of readableStream) {
  records.push(record);
}
readableStream.end();
knexClient.destroy();
```

we have checked the docs but couldn't find anything about events not working with streams.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: `knexClient.on('query-response', () => {
  console.log('query-response triggered!');
});

const records = [];
const readableStream = knexClient.raw('select * from columns').stream();
for await (const record of readableStream) {
  records.push(record);
}
readableStream.end();
knexClient.destroy();`